# Errors running MySQL queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, compatibility

I wrote queries in what is supposed to be standard SQL, and tested them in MySQL.

Now when I try to run them in PostgreSQL I get all sorts of errors, which I don't really understand.
Here's the original query, that works in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW popularCSsections AS (
    SELECT  sect.csid, COUNT(sc.sid) as numStudents
    FROM courseSection sect, studentCourse sc, department d
    WHERE sect.csid = sc.csid 
        AND sect.dcode = d.dcode 
        AND dname = "Computer Science"
    GROUP BY sect.csid
    HAVING numStudents > 2
);
```

gives this error:

```
psql:a2tables:60: ERROR:  column "Computer Science" does not exist
LINE 8:   AND department.dname = "Computer Science" 
                                 ^
```

Can you please help me understand the nature of the errors and help me fix them?

---

Additional issue:

```
CREATE VIEW popularCSsections AS (
SELECT  sect.csid, COUNT(sc.sid) as numStudents
FROM courseSection sect, studentCourse sc, department d
WHERE sect.csid = sc.csid 
    AND sect.dcode = d.dcode 
    AND dname = 'Computer Science'
    GROUP BY sect.csid
    HAVING numStudents > 2
);
```

Error:

```
psql:a2tables:70: ERROR:  column "numstudents" does not exist
LINE 8:  HAVING numStudents > 2
                ^
```

Comment: in standard SQL, strings are quoted using single-quote `'`, not double-quote `"`.  Try: `AND department.dname = 'Computer Science'`

Comment: "Standard SQL". Ha. *gigglesnort*. Sadly, standard SQL isn't particularly portable, and portable SQL isn't always standard SQL :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote strings with single quotes:

```
 AND dname = 'Computer Science'
```

What's happening here is that the double quotes are being interpreted as "identifier quotes" which signal that you want the contents interpreted as a database identifier (column or table name).

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm!!!

Now there is another error psql throws at me... any clue? (I added it to the orginal question)

Comment: Use `HAVING COUNT(sc.sid) > 2`.  Apparently, MySQL is not mapping the alias into the GROUP BY.

Comment: @LarryLustig MySQL *is* mapping the alias into the GROUP BY, even though it isn't allowed to by the spec. You can't refer to aliases from the SELECT list in the WHERE clause, GROUP BY, etc in standard SQL.

Comment: It is?  How do you make that out?  The (second) error that the OP is reporting is the inability to recognize the alias in the GROUP BY clause.